# Overriden BeforeClass method is stopping entire test execution

Tags: java, testng

I am using TestNG with Selenium WebDriver, the framework that I use has one base class which has BeforeClass method and all the Suite classes extend from this base class and have overriden BeforeClass methods as shown.

```
public BaseClass{
    @BeforeClass
    public void preConditions{
        //primary actions like opening browser and setting preferences
    }
}

public TestSuiteClass extends BaseClass{
    @BeforeClass
    @Override
    public void preConditions(){
        super.preCnditions();
        //specific preconditions required by test suite
    }
}
```

The problem I am have is, if an overridden method is failing for any reason,  all the test suits/cases gets skipped and entire test execution stops. 
How to stop this from happening?

Comment: which version of testng you are using ?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Could you add more test classes and methods? The goal is to show us what method tests are supposed to be run and what are not supposed.

Answer (score 1):

If something fails in @Before... annotated procedure the tests will be skipped instead of failing, because the problem is not with your test cases, but with the process before them. So it looks like your car cannot cross the river on a broken bridge, but it's not your car's fault.

If you really want to do some hacking about it, you can find [ideas here!](http://rolf-engelhard.de/2011/10/fail-instead-of-skip-a-test-when-testngs-dataprovider-throws-an-exception/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a way around this, but you need to consider if you realy want to do it. The idea of the method with `@BeforeClass` annotation is to set relevant data for the test (you even called it `preConditions`). If it fails, the test won't pass anyway.

One way to do it is to remove the `@BeforeClass` annotation and call the method from the test itself

```
public TestSuiteClass etends BaseClass {

    public void customPreConditions() {
        super.preCnditions();
    }

    @Test
    publuc void someTest() {
        customPreConditions();
        // do the test
    }
}
```

The test will continue even if `customPreConditions()` is not successful.